# Why is my teleporting not working? (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

so in my game, I made another place in the asset manager. For some reason I cant teleport to it. It says teleport failed and in the console it says the place is not published. The game is published. And I dont think you have to publish places. I am using ReserveServer and TeleportToPrivateServer. I have tried to figure it out and my game IS published. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to publish the place inside of your place (asset manager) like so:

**Step 1:**

Open the place inside the asset manager by double clicking it:
[image: asset manager is located on left side of the view]

**Step 2:**

Once you are inside the place (which is from the asset manager), then proceed to publish the place like so:
[image: publishing the place inside of asset manager]

**Summary**: make sure to publish the place you have added/created in the asset manager

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I didn’t realise at the time you had to publish the second game too.

Comment: @TrulyBlue thank you for setting my answer as the correct answer despite that you have already solved it long ago!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing it in an actual game setting instead of just roblox studio? Also make sure both games are public.

Edit: The games don't need to be public

Comment: I have been testing it inside the actual game and not roblox studio and it is not a whole seperate game or "experience". it is just another place I made in the asset manager. ive never has to publish them before so I cant see the problem. I am using ReserveServer and TeleportToPrivateServer for the teleporting.

Comment: games don't need to be public in order for this to work, you can test this while the game is still in development and private, please clarify.

Comment: I didn’t realise at the time I had to publish the game created in the asset manager, and that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the TeleportService:Teleport function, rather than TeleportAsync, if you need to teleport to a private server, I'd suggest just not using Async, as async teleport functions have had b
Here's a usage case:
`game:GetService("TeleportService"):Teleport(123456, game.Players:GetPlayers()[1])`

Arguments being place id, player. In TeleportToPrivateServer, which you would need if you're specifically teleporting to a private server (which you stated you were using, the usage case is
`game:GetService("TeleportService"):TeleportToPrivateServer(placeID,code,player)`
You likely already know this, but if you were missing something, or using the wrong variables, it could be a fix.

If that doesn't solve your problem, make sure:

1. In Game Settings > Security Third Party Teleports are enabled
2. Your referenced player variable, or place id aren't nil
3. And make sure the place has been published

Keep in mind, you can't teleport in Roblox Studio, so you should know it works if you get an error in the console stating you may not teleport in the roblox studio.

Comment: I’m just looking back at my unanswered questions, at the time I didn’t realise you had to publish the game created in the asset manager, and that was the problem.